# Explanation of a few points in Alan Turing's, 'On the Computable Numbers'

Tags: turing-machines

I have recently been reading Alan Turing's *On the Computable Numbers, With an Application to the Entscheidungsproblem*, and found it fairly straight forward at first, but was confused on some points in §5 and §8.

Firstly, in §5 page 240, Turing switches to a new way of notation, in which each lines operation will contain a print, saying that lines that will neither print nor erase, can be written like so: *q<sub>1</sub> S<sub>j</sub> PS<sub>j</sub> q<sub>2</sub>* However, a paragraph down the page, when he explains how to convert m-configurations to strings of letters, he provides no equivalent, 'D' is erase, 'DA' is print 0, and 'DAA' is print 1. How would someone express printing nothing with a string of letters?

Second, in §8 page 247, I am confused about Turing's description of *H*. What does Turing mean "The machine *H* has its motion divided into sections," does he mean each square is a section? Are sections more than one square long?

Lastly, on the same page and section, Turing uses a constant or function, not sure which, R. He uses expretions such as R(N-1), is R being multiplied by N-1? But how can R(N-1) of the sections where there are N sections be found unless R<1? If R<1 why not say (N-1)/R? What exactly is R doing here?

The PDF I used: [https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Erobins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### String descriptions of machines

The exact description of how he converts an instruction to a string is:

> In this description we shall replace $q_i$ by the letter "D" followed by the letter "A" repeated $i$ times, and $S_j$ by "D" followed by "C" repeated $j$ times.

So the instruction $q_1 S_0 S_2 L q_2$, representing "If we are in state $q_1$ and the current space on the tape is blank, write a 1, move one space to the left and go to state $q_2$", would be written as "DADDCCLDAA".

If by "print nothing" you mean "print a blank", then that is represented by the symbol "D" followed by zero "C"s. However, if by "print nothing" you mean "leave the current symbol unchanged", it has no explicit representation in Turing's notation but instead you would have an instruction that includes $S_i S_i$, i.e. "if the current symbol is $S_i$, then erase it and print the symbol $S_i$". If you have an entire state that leaves the current space unchanged, then that would involve having one of these instructions for each possible symbol in this particular state.

### The decision machine

In saying that $\mathcal{H}$ has its motion divided into sections, Turing is saying that it performs an iterative process that operates over the numbers $1, 2, 3, \ldots$. He is defining a function $R$ that returns "the number of circle-free machines represented by the integers from $1$ to $N$". It does so by simply writing down the integers, and using the decision machine $\mathcal{D}$ to check whether the most recently written integer is the DN of a circle-free machine. If it is, then $R(N) = R(N-1) + 1$, and if it isn't then $R(N) = R(N-1)$. There is an implicit $R(0) = 0$ to start the process off.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I completly get the first part, concerning the SDs,  it makes so much sence that I can't believe I hadn't relised that. 

The second part I'm not sure if I get though. So N is the ND of a m-config, and R(N) returns the the number(not the ND) of the nearest circle-free machine equal to or less than N. IE: if X is the first circle-free ND, then R(x)=1, and if x+1 isn't circle free, then R(x+1)=1, and if X+2 is the ND of a circle free machine, then R(x+2)=2, is this correct?

Comment: Not quite - $R(N)$ is counting how many numbers from 1 to $N$ are NDs of circle-free machines. So suppose that 1, 3, 6, 10 were all valid NDs, then $R(1) = R(2) = 1$, $R(3) = R(4) = R(5) = 2$, $R(6) = R(7) = R(8) = R(9) = 3$, and $R(10) = 4$.

Comment: So if 1, 3, 6, & 10 are circle free, and R(0)=0, then:
R(0)=0
R(1)=1 because 1 is circle free and R(1-1)+1=1
R(2)=1 because 2 isn't circle free and R(2-1)=1
R(3)=2 because 3 is circle free and R(3-1)+1=2
R(4)=2 because 4 isn't circle free and R(4-1)=2
R(5)=2 because 5 isn't circle free and R(5-1)=2
R(6)=2 because 6 is circle free and R(6-1)+1=3

Now do I have it?

Comment: Yep, looks like you have it now.